# How to fix "use of extern prelude names introduced with `extern crate` items is unstable"

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

When I run `cargo build` (even after `cargo clean`) the crate `v_escape_derive` version 0.2.1 cannot be compiled. I receive the following message:

```
error[E0658]: use of extern prelude names introduced with `extern crate` items is unstable (see issue #55599)
 --> /Users/***/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-***/v_escape_derive-0.2.1/src/lib.rs:7:5
  |
7 | use proc_macro::TokenStream;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = help: add #![feature(extern_crate_item_prelude)] to the crate attributes to enable
```

I tried running `cargo clean` before `cargo build` with no success.

When I saw these `extern crate` errors before, the problem was about `edition  =2015`, but the edition for my project is `2018` and there's no `extern crate ...` line in my project files. As far as I can see, the problem is within an external `lib.rs` file (i.e. the inner file of that `v_escape_derive` package so I don't think it's a good idea to change it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even in Rust 2018, [some crates are special and **must** be imported via `extern crate`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/module-system/path-clarity.html#an-exception). This includes the `proc_macro` crate.

To fix the problem, add an `extern crate proc_macro;` line to the code.

> as far as I can see, the problem is within [another crate]

Then you have to file an issue against that crate; it doesn't work in stable Rust.

Specifically regarding [v_escape_derive 0.2.1](https://crates.io/crates/v_escape_derive/0.2.1); that's an old version. The [current version is 0.4](https://crates.io/crates/v_escape_derive) does not have this issue. Upgrade your dependencies to incorporate the update.

See also:

- [Path clarity — exceptions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/module-system/path-clarity.html#an-exception)

Comment: The problem is that I don't need `v_escape_derive-0.2.1` directly (I don't use it), it was imported through another package (you can see the problem is in `lib.rs` file which is an inner file of `v_escape_derive-0.2.1`). Do you still think it's a good idea to change the source code of that package?

Comment: @JamesLarkin that's how dependencies work. If a package you use uses a package, then you must compile both packages. Fixing the upstream package is the only solution.

Comment: Well, is there a way to make my package import the latest version of `v_escape_derive` package which is `0.4.0` now (v_escape_derive = "0.4.0")? One interesting thing is that that repo compiles on my home computer w/o any errors (and I can see that error on my desktop at work).

Comment: @JamesLarkin sounds like you either haven't committed your [Cargo.lock](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/guide/cargo-toml-vs-cargo-lock.html) file or your compiler versions are drastically different. A tool like [cargo tree](https://github.com/sfackler/cargo-tree) can show you what is bringing in the old version.